# Spark SQL HyperLogLog returning Bytes and count both

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to run HyperLogLog in Spark which returns the byte associated so that I could save them and next time when I re-run the method, I will use the current input+previous bytes and then re-run HLL.
Approx_distinct only gives the count.
I am using twitter chill APi -

```
    val instantiator = new ScalaKryoInstantiator
    instantiator.setRegistrationRequired(false)
    val kryo = instantiator.newKryo()
    kryo.register(classOf[Array[com.twitter.algebird.HLL]])
    kryo.register(classOf[com.twitter.algebird.SparseHLL])
    kryo.register(classOf[com.twitter.algebird.Max[_]])


   var meredSeq:Seq[HLL] = hllSeq
    if(hbaseData != null && meredSeq != null && hbaseData.length > 0){
      val input = new Input(new ByteArrayInputStream(hbaseData))
      val deserialized:Seq[HLL] = kryo.readObject(input,classOf[Array[com.twitter.algebird.HLL]])
      if(deserialized != null && deserialized.length > 0)
        meredSeq = hllSeq ++ deserialized
    }

val hllSum = hll.sum(meredSeq)
```

From above I am always saving the HLL output as Byte Array and again merge with current set of data. It works but not effiecient.

Comment: Do you get any Solution?

Comment: I used Twitter HLL and customized that based on my need, you can extend existing Spark HLL and tweak it as you need